# Load Stimulus controllers from *multiple* directories in Symfony's Webpack Encore

Tags: symfony, webpack-encore, stimulusjs

With the default `bootstrap.js` (from [symfony/webpack-encore-bundle](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/main/symfony/webpack-encore-bundle/1.10/assets/bootstrap.js)) ...

```js
import { startStimulusApp } from '@symfony/stimulus-bridge';

// Registers Stimulus controllers from controllers.json and in the controllers/ directory
export const app = startStimulusApp(require.context(
    '@symfony/stimulus-bridge/lazy-controller-loader!./controllers',
    true,
    /\.[jt]sx?$/,
));
```

... Stimulus controllers are loaded from `assets/controllers/`.

Is there a way to also load controllers from another directory?

Answer (score 1):

Add this `import` to `controllers.js`:

```js
import { definitionsFromContext } from '@hotwired/stimulus-webpack-helpers';
```

and at the bottom:

```js
app.load(definitionsFromContext(require.context(
    '@symfony/stimulus-bridge/lazy-controller-loader!../foo/bar/more_controllers',
    true,
    /\.[jt]sx?$/
)));
```

Sources:

- The idea is taken from https://github.com/symfony/stimulus-bridge/issues/44#issuecomment-1064176223
- ... and combined with the Stimulus documentation: https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/handbook/installing#using-webpack-helpers
- Another related issue: https://github.com/symfony/stimulus-bridge/issues/29